# How to properly align multiple rows and columns of plots?

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats

My plots are getting misaligned between the rows because of the negative values on the y axis. They're also way too far to the right. Is there any way to fix this?

What it looks like:

[image]

My code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat{%}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xlabel = {x},
ylabel = {y},
title = {0\degree}]%
\addplot[%
each nth point=100, 
filter discard warning=false, 
unbounded coords=discard,
color = blue,
only marks,
mark size = 0.8]
table[x index= 0,y index = 1,col sep=tab] {fi1.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\subfloat{%}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xlabel = {x},
ylabel = {y},
title = {72\degree}]%
\addplot[%
each nth point=100, 
filter discard warning=false, 
unbounded coords=discard,
color = blue,
only marks,
mark size = 0.8]
table[x index= 0,y index = 1,col sep=tab] {fi2.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\qquad
\subfloat{%}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xlabel = {x},
ylabel = {y},
title = {144\degree}]%
\addplot[%
each nth point=100, 
filter discard warning=false, 
 unbounded coords=discard,
 color = blue,
 only marks,
 mark size = 0.8]
 table[x index= 0,y index = 1,col sep=tab] {fi3.txt};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }%
 \subfloat{%}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[%
 xlabel = {x},
 ylabel = {y},
 title = {216\degree}]%
 \addplot[%
 each nth point=100, 
 filter discard warning=false, 
 unbounded coords=discard,
 color = blue,
 only marks,
 mark size = 0.8]
 table[x index= 0,y index = 1,col sep=tab] {fi4.txt};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }%
 \qquad
 \subfloat{%}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[%
 xlabel = {x},
 ylabel = {y},
 title = {288\degree}]%
 \addplot[%
 each nth point=100, 
 filter discard warning=false, 
 unbounded coords=discard,
 color = blue,
 only marks,
 mark size = 0.8]
 table[x index= 0,y index = 1,col sep=tab] {fi5.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Could you turn your code into a complete example so that we can compile it directly without making any modifications? We don't have your data files for example, but you can use `\addplot coordinates {(-15,-15)(5,5)};` or similar instead, as the exact data isn't necessary for demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need captions for each axis, I would suggest dropping the `\subfloat`s altogether. They're not needed. I would also suggest putting the first four axes in a `groupplot` environment, then alignment is default. By only having axis labels on the outer edges you can also save some space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{showframe} % for example, shows boundaries of text area
\newcommand{\degree}{$^\circ$} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[%
xlabel = {x},
ylabel = {y},
width=0.5\linewidth,
group style={
  group size={2 by 2},
  vertical sep=1.5cm,
  ylabels at=edge left,
  xlabels at=edge bottom},
every axis plot/.style={
  %each nth point=100, 
  filter discard warning=false, 
  unbounded coords=discard,
  color = blue,
  only marks,
  mark size = 0.8}
]%
\nextgroupplot[title = {0\degree}]
\addplot coordinates{(-5,-20)(12,0)};

\nextgroupplot[title = {72\degree}]%
\addplot coordinates{(0,0)(19,10)};

\nextgroupplot[title = {144\degree}]%
\addplot coordinates{(-5,-20)(12,0)};

\nextgroupplot[title = {216\degree}]%
 \addplot coordinates{(-5,-20)(12,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  xlabel = {x},
  ylabel = {y},
  title = {288\degree}]%
\addplot[%
% each nth point=100, 
 filter discard warning=false, 
 unbounded coords=discard,
 color = blue,
 only marks,
 mark size = 0.8]
coordinates{(-5,-20)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]